# ¿Cómo conectarse a la base de datos de un sub-servidor?

Tags: php, sql, base-de-datos

Tengo un servidor físico con varias instalaciones de servidores. De modo que la forma de acceder a un sub-servidor de forma pública mediante un navegador, es:

1º Añadir estas dos líneas en /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
ProxyPass /nombre_proyecto http://iplocal_subservidor:8080/carpeta_proyecto/login.xhtml
ProxyPassReverse /nombre_proyecto http://iplocal_subservidor:8080/carpeta_proyecto/login.xhtml
```

2º Conectarse al sub-servidor a través de la ip del servidor físico: http://ip_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto

Hecho esto, quiero conectarme a la base de datos de un sub-servidor mediante el uso de php en una aplicación de phonegap. Esto funciona en localhost:

```
$host = "localhost";
$usuario = "usuario";
$pass = "contrasena";
$bd = "nombre_bd";

$server = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario, $pass, $bd);
```

Pero necesito una conexión que no sea local a la base de datos del sub-servidor. He probado con estas versiones de $host, pero no he conseguido que funcione:

```
$host = "ip_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto";
$host = "http://ip_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto";
$host = "nombre_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto";
$host = "http://nombre_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto";
```

Comment: `$host = "ip_servidor_fisico:puerto";` es todo lo que necesitas.

Comment: ¿Pero qué puerto? No tengo ni idea de por qué puerto accede de un servidor a otro y no tienen la misma base de datos.

Comment: El puerto estándar de mysql es el 3306, en cuyo caso, puedes omitirlo y usar solo `$host = "ip_servidor_fisico";` La base de datos, configúrala en tu variable `$bd`

Comment: El caso es que usando "ip_servidor_fisico/nombre_proyecto" funciona en red local y accede bien a la base de datos. Si sólo le meto "ip_servidor_fisico" accedería a la base de datos incorrecta, tiene que acceder a la que hay en la otra máquina virtual.

Comment: Y si haciéndolo así te funciona... ¿Dónde está el problema original?

Comment: Que sólo funciona en red local. Si accedo desde otra red, no me sirve.

Comment: ¿Con `sub-servidor` te referís a una PC virtual creada con, por ejemplo, `VMWare` o `VirtualBox`? Si es así ¿la red de la misma, está configurada en `NAT` o `Sólo host`? ¿es posible cambiarle esa configuración a `Bridge`?

Comment: Sí, es una máquina virtual. Pero no tengo ni idea de cómo está configurada la red ni creo que pueda tocarla.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurren 3 alternativas:

1. Cambiar la configuración de red de la PC virtual a `Bridge`, de esta forma se va a poder acceder a esta desde la red como si fuera otra PC más.

   **En VirtualBox**
   [image: Adaptador puente en VirtualBox]
   **En VMWare**
   [image: Adaptador puente en VMWare]

   Luego habrá que configurar el adaptador de red de la PC virtual, que si está en DHCP tendría que detectar la nueva red (suponiendo que haya un servidor DHCP), sino tocará asignar la IP de la red de forma manual.
2. Crear una PC virtual que haga de puente entre la red real y la de la PC virtual. Por ejemplo con pfSense. A grandes razgos la PC virtual tendría 2 interfaces, la WAN dentro de la red local a la que pertenece el servidor host físico y la LAN a la red a la que pertenece la PC virtual que tiene la base de datos. Luego crear un redireccionamiento de puertos a la PC virtual con la base de datos. Lo que hay que asegurarse acá es que la PC virtual de la base de datos tenga como gateway la IP de la PC virtual con pfSense.

   Por ejemplo, suponiendo que tu red local sea `192.168.0.0/24` (que el servidor físico tenga IP `192.168.0.1`) y la red interna entre el servidor físico y el virtual sea `10.0.2.0/24` (y el servidor virtual tenga IP `10.0.2.3`), entonces la WAN de pfSense podría ser `192.168.0.150` y la LAN `10.0.2.150`. Entonces en pfSense redireccionarías los puertos que hagan falta a `10.0.2.3`. Es **muy importante** que la PC vitual tenga como gateway la IP de pfSense, en el caso del ejemplo entonces sería `10.0.2.150`.
3. Existe un programa [mysql proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/), no es recomendable usarlo para producción pero a lo mejor te sirve. Lo comentan en [Redirect mysql queries to another server](https://serverfault.com/questions/460231/redirect-mysql-queries-to-another-server).

Los 2 primeros los he probado y sé que funcionan. Lo último nunca lo probé, así que no sabría cómo configurarlo.